# Connect to Windows shared folder in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, ubuntu, samba

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. Moreover, I have a share folder in windows of another computer. I have to access the share folder in Ubuntu. Therefore, I installed samba client using this command:

```
sudo apt install samba smbclient
```

I go in the browser file of Ubuntu and enter this URL to connect the share folder:

```
smb://X.X.X.X/shared
```

But, after entering name and domain, I cannot enter to the share folder. I also add this line in smb.conf:

```
client max protocol = NT1
```

Then run these command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nmbd restart
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
```

Also, I add IP and Username of Windows Machine to the /etc/hosts file. Now when I try to connect to the share folder I receive this error:

```
Failed to mount windows share : invalid argument
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You are forcing (unsecure) SMB1 which is now disabled by default both in Linux and Windows.  I am have fixed this before but can't remember how but I can tell you that it is probably because of the SMBx version.  You can tell your windows side to allow that protocol but that would make the machine much more insecure.

Comment: Temporarily enable the SMBv1 protocol on Windows 10  and see if it works. Launch Turn Windows features on or off, expand the SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support option. Check the SMB 1.0/CIFS Client option. Click the OK button and restart.